# What's the use of --single-argument %1 in this registry path?

Tags: windows-registry

In this registry path:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\open\command]
```

there is a key with this value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"  --single-argument %1
```

What's the use of: `--single-argument %1`

is this simply a place holder? is it ok to remove it or replace it with a commandline switch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Concerning %1 :**

%1 represent the file used as param of the msedge command. So basically it's your "MSEdgHTM" file.
If you remove it, open a MSEdgeHTM file will just open msedge.exe without opening the file inside it.

**Concerning --single-argument :**

Msedge is chromium based, you can find information about this argument directly in [chromium source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/base/command_line.h) :

> The single-argument switch prevents unexpected parsing of arguments
> from other software that cannot be trusted to escape double quotes
> when substituting into a placeholder (e.g., "%1" placeholders
> populated by the Windows shell).

So it's purpose is to be sure that the next argument (%1) will be interpreted correctly as a single argument.

It's probably better to keep it.

Comment: Just to say this explicitly for clarity: `--single-argument` is passed to the Edge executable literally.

Comment: Thank you, but what is a "MSEdgHTM" file? I've never come across a file with that extension. could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: MSEdgeHTM is not an extension but a file type.
You can get the associated extension of this file type by using the cmd command `assoc | find "MSEdgeHTM"`