# My Chrome profile is reset when opening a file if Chrome is not running when the file is opened

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium, reset, profile

I'm running [Chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) and every time a file is opened with it **while it's closed**, the Default profile is completely reset.

In other words:

1. chrome.exe is not running
2. Open any file with chrome.exe, e.g. example.html, example.webp, etc.
3. File opens in chrome.exe and profile is reset

If Chromium is running when the file is opened, the profile is not reset.

Chromium is set as the default browser in Settings.app > Apps > Default apps > Web browser = Chromium

My startup shortcut for chrome.exe is this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Chromium\chrome.exe"
    --disable-machine-id 
    --show-avatar-button=never 
    --hide-tab-close-buttons 
    --tab-hover-cards=none 
    --disable-sharing-hub 
    --hide-sidepanel-button 
    --disable-search-engine-collection 
    --enable-features=DisableLinkDrag
```

I think the problem has something to do with Windows opening the file without using any of the flags I have defined in the main shortcut I use, but not really sure.

Looking for a solution, if anyone has suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well by golly I figured it out with the help of [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/a/600149/11369)

Had to edit the registry like so:

```
; ORIGINAL:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromiumHTM.7L7JSISFHDLFXQAF5SCUQPAZGY\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Chromium\\chrome.exe\" --single-argument %1"

; NEW:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromiumHTM.7L7JSISFHDLFXQAF5SCUQPAZGY\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Chromium\\chrome.exe\"
 --disable-machine-id
 --show-avatar-button=never
 --hide-tab-close-buttons
 --tab-hover-cards=none
 --disable-sharing-hub
 --hide-sidepanel-button
 --disable-search-engine-collection
 --enable-features=DisableLinkDrag
 --single-argument %1"
```

Seems to work fine without the default `--single-argument` flag present, but [I would keep it for escaping purposes](https://superuser.com/a/1621151/11369).